# Why this Debian-ex-developer public key not found?

Tags: debian, software-installation, gpg

I am followings instructions [Install from Debian, Ubuntu, or Mint using the command line and GnuPG](https://tails.boum.org/install/expert/usb/index.en.html) in making *Tails*, based on Debian, usb stick.

All steps done where the failure in the last line `gpg: error reading key: public key not found`, while expected output `sig! 0x9C31503C6D866396 2015-02-03  Stefano Zacchiroli <zack@upsilon.cc>` to the command `gpg --keyid-format 0xlong --check-sigs A490D0F4D311A4153E2BB7CADBB802B258ACD84F`

```
masi@masi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)
Release:    8.7
Codename:   jessie

masi@masi:~$ wget https://tails.boum.org/tails-signing.key
--2017-02-26 08:47:14--  https://tails.boum.org/tails-signing.key
Resolving tails.boum.org (tails.boum.org)... 204.13.164.188
Connecting to tails.boum.org (tails.boum.org)|204.13.164.188|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 459593 (449K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘tails-signing.key’

tails-signing.key   100%[=====================>] 448.82K   351KB/s   in 1.3s   

2017-02-26 08:47:17 (351 KB/s) - ‘tails-signing.key’ saved [459593/459593]

masi@masi:~$ gpg --import < tails-signing.key
gpg: key 58ACD84F: public key "Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found

masi@masi:~$ su
Password: 

root@masi:/home/masi# apt-get install debian-keyring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libx265-79 linux-image-4.6.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 linux-image-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  debian-keyring
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 52.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 58.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main debian-keyring all 2015.04.10 [52.4 MB]
Fetched 52.4 MB in 35s (1,458 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package debian-keyring.
(Reading database ... 316032 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../debian-keyring_2015.04.10_all.deb ...
Unpacking debian-keyring (2015.04.10) ...
Setting up debian-keyring (2015.04.10) ...
root@masi:/home/masi# gpg --keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-keyring.gpg --export zack@upsilon.cc | gpg --import
gpg: key 6D866396: public key "Stefano Zacchiroli <zack@upsilon.cc>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found

root@masi:/home/masi# gpg --keyid-format 0xlong --check-sigs A490D0F4D311A4153E2BB7CADBB802B258ACD84F
gpg: error reading key: public key not found
```

OS: Debian 8.7
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UB

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't imported the Tails key that you try to check the signatures on:

```
$ gpg --recv-key A490D0F4D311A4153E2BB7CADBB802B258ACD84F

$ gpg --check-sigs A490D0F4D311A4153E2BB7CADBB802B258ACD84F
pub   rsa4096 2015-01-18 [C] [expires: 2018-01-11]
      A490D0F4D311A4153E2BB7CADBB802B258ACD84F
uid           [ unknown] Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!         9C31503C6D866396 2015-02-03  Stefano Zacchiroli <zack@upsilon.cc>
sig!3        DBB802B258ACD84F 2015-09-27  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        DBB802B258ACD84F 2016-08-30  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        DBB802B258ACD84F 2015-01-18  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
uid           [ unknown] Tails developers <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        DBB802B258ACD84F 2015-09-27  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sig!3        DBB802B258ACD84F 2016-08-30  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sub   rsa4096 2015-01-18 [S] [expires: 2018-01-11]
sig!         DBB802B258ACD84F 2016-08-30  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@bgpg: 9 good signatures
gpg: 1124 signatures not checked due to missing keys
oum.org>
sub   rsa4096 2015-01-18 [S] [expires: 2018-01-11]
sig!         DBB802B258ACD84F 2016-08-30  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
sub   rsa4096 2016-08-30 [S] [expires: 2018-01-11]
sig!         DBB802B258ACD84F 2016-08-30  Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>
```

Well, you did, but you did it as an ordinary user, while trying to check the signature as root.  You now have two keyrings, one with the Tails key in your user account, and one with the Debian developer's key in the root account.

This is one of the reasons you should use `sudo` and *very seldom* find yourself with an interactive root shell.

Comment: I have to consider using `sudo` once again, since without `sudo` can clearly be problematic.